# Leave the hover state only when a specifc time is reached

Tags: jquery, timer

In the following block of code, i'm trying find a way to leave the hover state ONLY after a specific time ( for exemple 500ms )

```
<div id='a' style="border:2px solid black" >
  <h3>Hover</h3></br>
</div>
<div id="test" style="background-color:red">
  display
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test").hide();
  var delay = 200, setTimeoutConst;

  $('#a').hover(function() {
    setTimeoutConst = setTimeout(function() {
      $("#test").show();
    }, delay);
  }, function() {
    // execute here ONLY if 500ms have passed outside of the control being hovered
  })
})
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: To clarify. Do you want to keep it visible for 500ms after the mouse exists?

Comment: You already have the exact logic you need using the timer in the first `hover` handler function...?

Comment: Joraid : Yes that's exactly what i want to do. if the time spent outside the hovered control is < to 500ms, the block of code must not be executed

Comment: So why not do the same thing for the second function, but with a 500 ms delay rather than 200 ?  Like Rory was suggesting.

Comment: Because if i do that, the code will still be executed, it's just delayed. I don't want it to be executed at all if the time is < to 500ms

Comment: I think i see the issue you are concerned about

Comment: I think i'm not clear enough guys... my mistake.
Basicallly , if i leave the hover and do circles with my mouse outside during 400ms and then return to the control with the hover, nothing should happen. Only if i stay out during more than 500ms

Comment: You have to clear the previous timeout so it does not happen in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

```js
 
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#test").hide();
   var delay=200, setTimeoutConst, myTime;
  
 $('#a').hover(function(){
        setTimeoutConst = setTimeout(function(){
           $("#test").show();
           //Here is the missign part. clearTimeout so the callback won't be executed. 
           clearTimeout(myTime); 
        }, delay);
   },function(){
   
   myTime=  setTimeout(function(){
      
       $("#test").hide( ); 
   }, 500);
        //execute here ONLY if 500ms has passed outside of the control being hovered
   })
   
   
   
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='a' style="border:2px solid black" >
<h3>Hover</h3>
</br>
</div>
<div id="test" style="background-color:red">
display
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not what i'm looking for. The .hide() is just delayed. I don't want it to hide at all if i stay outside from the "a" control less than 500ms

Comment: Then you should clear the timeout at the start of the method so that it cancelled the last timeout that did not trigger in the delay time frame.

Comment: @ArnaudAd Ouh. So if the mouse exists and returns very very quicly, less than 500ms the div should remain visible?

Comment: joraid: exactly !

Comment: @Taplar is absolutely correct.  So I canceled the timeOut if the mouse returned. Check my update.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test").hide();
  var delay = 200, setTimeoutConst;

  $('#a').hover(function() {
    //clear the timeout incase it was going to hide it
    clearTimeout(setTimeoutConst);
    setTimeoutConst = setTimeout(function() {
      $("#test").show();
    }, delay);
  }, function() {
    //clear the timeout incase it was going to show it again
    clearTimeout(setTimeoutConst);
    setTimeoutConst = setTimeout(function() {
      $("#test").hide();
    }, 500);
  })
})
```